# Navigate a large HTML file with Vim and ctags

Tags: html, vim, ctags

Is it possible to generate a tag file with ctags (5.8) for a single, large HTML file (about 50 MB) so it can be easier navigated within Vim?

Comment: To what places in the file you would like to jump? IDs, tag names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround without ctags I tried this plugin [Quick-Filter](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2759). It works for me. 
I imagine a solution with ctags would be nice, too.

Answer (score 2):

If you issue the following command you will see what tags are produced for a given language.

```
ctags --list-kinds=html
a  named anchors
f  JavaScript functions
```

If those tags were not good enough there is always the possibility to add to more with RegEx.

http://ctags.sourceforge.net/EXTENDING.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to navigate to tag names *(as said in the comment)*, then I suppose that simple search would work better. An index where you have registered every occurrence of `<p>`,`<span>` and so on, would be much larger that the indexed file itself.

To find a tag (for example `<p class="x">`), just try <kbd>/</kbd><kbd><</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>\</kbd><kbd>></kbd>

The sequence <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>></kbd> matches an "end of the word", so it will not match `<pre>` for example.

If you want to navigate to an ID, you may just press an asterisk <kbd>*</kbd> - this will find you the next occurrence of the word under cursor.